# Create list based on index of existing list

Tags: python

I know how to create a new list based on the values of an existing list, eg casting

```
numspec = [float(x) for x in textspec]
```

Now I have a list of numbers where I need to subtract a value based on the index of a list. I have calculated an a and b value and ended up doing

```
peakadj = []
for i in range(len(peakvalues)):
    val=peakvalues[i]-(i*a+b)
    peakadj.append(val)
```

This works, but I don't like the feel of it, is there any more pythonic way of doing this?

Answer (score 4):

Use the builtin [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function and a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
peakadj = [val-(i*a+b) for i, val in enumerate(peakvalues)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps faster:

```
from itertools import count

peakadj = [val-iab for val, iab in zip(peakvalues, count(b, a))]
```

Or:

```
from itertools import count
from operator import sub

peakadj = [*map(sub, peakvalues, count(b, a))]
```

[Little benchmark](https://tio.run/##hZBbTsMwEEX/s4r5qWoHUyVNeUpdAUuoqsgJE7AaP@TYSGXzYZyUUhAIS5GcGc@5x3bH8GpNde/8OD5jB0/Y98eS8ccMaHkM0RvYvcn@WskGOuuB9gLSjzLwrhxzKA9UizgIaG00gTUCJOf7LDsD1z@BuZaODZFO/jNuVHv4zYapXF41fDJSIkklHzRRo5cBL6wSqYumHWB7up04SYmJTl1vNaiAPljbD6C0sz7MMnPPugRNSXOLxOdGUBpV@Cx7pNSQZV/ZFLmrRCk29N2IB7EWt/tMCmioQfF3lE3UZJfsJ8v5qs4reolUYJx/I@ZbKIuimAbrNOWleUFW8ctBPu3/YKcVSEArw2blKYheI@oG/bYsOD8fnHnLxWZVdqAHWMICWIAcSqy4mLCrujZSY13zcfwA)